# Problems with tesseract and leptonica on OS X

Tags: install, macports

after `sudo port selfupdate`, `sudo port install leptonica` and `sudo port install tesseract` I have what seem to be serious deficiencies. Tesseract wont even recognize .tiff files!

```
pro:Images me$ tesseract textcrop.tiff textcrop
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
Error in findTiffCompression: function not present
Error in pixReadStreamTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadStream: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Unsupported image type.

pro:Images me$ otool -L `which tesseract`
/usr/local/bin/tesseract:
    /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.2.0)
    /usr/local/lib/liblept.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
```

I am running OS X 10.8.4. I have tried cleaning and reinstalling both leptonica and tesseract with no results.